# Able to ping Domain internal address on home network, why?

Tags: ipv4, vpn, dns

I have a strange issue, I am able to ping my company's internal address (ex: hq.mycomapny.com) when I am on my Home network (WI-FI or Enthernet) and NOT connected to the VPN.
When I do a ping on the ip for hq.mycompany.com with the "-a" flag I also get a successful reply  that has the ip address in the reply with the following text appended to it ".deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com" so it looks something like this (ex: a28-103-218-107.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com). 
Does any one know why I am able to ping my domain internal adders while not connected to the internal network or the VPN? and what is the (".deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com") text in the ping reply.
Could it be using a DNS cache in my router/modem from the previous time I connected to the VPN (just throwing ideas out there)? 
I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You aren't pinging an address; you're pinging a public resolvable name. Internally it may resolve to a different address.

Comment: I stand corrected, I am pinging a public name (I should have used proper terminology). But why is it resolving to some other address?

Comment: Because it does. Ask your IT department why their DNS records are what they are.

Comment: @RickyBeam to your earlier comment, I am NOT pinging a public resolvable name, what I am pinging a pravat FQDN that should only resolve if there is connection to the company network, the problem is when I ping that FQDN on my home ntwork it is resolving to an address associated with akami technologies (ex: a45-207-67-105.deploy.static.akamitechnologies.com) and thats causing problems for me and concern.

Comment: You asked a public DNS server for a name and got a public IP answer. That's the very definition of *public resolvable name*. You didn't ask for an internal name (example.local, example.inside, etc. i.e. a TLD that *does not exist on the public internet*) The fact that www.example.com resolves to different numbers inside vs. outside is irrelevant; it is resolvable in both cases. It may be an ISP NXDOMAIN trap, but one would expect mycompany.com to exist outside the company. If "hq" resolves, someone put a record in for it.

Answer (score 3):

You are pinging to public resolve name. Therefore you are getting reply. You cannot ping directly to internal network. If you are getting reply from unexpected Ip address there will be many reasons.

- Your domain under DNS Spoofing Attack. Try to Resolve IP address Using `nslookup` command.
- Your computer might assign alias for that particular domain. clean your cache with `ipconfig /flushdns`. And check your host File.
- Sometimes mac address of both servers may be same because of configuration mistake. (This statement valid only if both servers are located in same network.)